# How to take string between two characters in redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, substring, amazon-redshift

I have this column in my redshift table and I need to take the string comes after `[` and before `-`

```
note_internal

package received by [THP - (YBS)]; notes: (Status Manual by jack)
package received by [THP Head Office TRIP 1 - (HO)]; notes: (Status Manual by jack)
```

The expected result:

```
result

THP
THP Head Office Trip 1
```

I have tried to use `substring` syntax but it did not work

```
substring(note_internal,charindex('[',note_internal)+1,(((len(note_internal))-charindex('-', reverse(note_internal)))-charindex('-',note_internal))) as result
```

How can I get my expected result to extract the string after `[` and before `'`?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use [REGEXP_SUBSTR function - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/REGEXP_SUBSTR.html), perhaps like this:

```
SELECT regexp_substr(note_internal, '\[(.*)-', 1, 1, 'e')
```

It is saying:

- `\[` Find the first square bracket
- `(.*)` Grab lots of characters and mark it as a group to return
- `-` Find a dash
- `1` Start at position 1
- `1` Return the first occurence
- `e` Extract a substring using a subexpression

(I don't have Redshift running so couldn't test it, but let us know how it goes!)

Comment: thank you for the help. I tried the syntax but it gives me error saying ```ERROR: Unmatched [ or [^ in character class declaration. The error occurred while parsing the regular expression: '[(.*)```

Comment: You'll need to debug the regex expression to figure out the right syntax. Start with `'received(.*)notes'` to see what it is doing -- that should return everything between 'received' and 'notes'. Then, try changing it to match on the square bracket instead. You'll need to prefix the square bracket with `\` since it normally has a special meaning.